# Updating os module with pip results in an error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
C:\Users\Personal>pip install --upgrade os
Collecting os
  Using cached os-0.5.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\personal\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Personal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-hlmmdd48\\os\\setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Personal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-hlmmdd48\os\
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to update the `os` module? It's [part of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).

Answer (score 2):

The `os` module is part of Pythons standard library, you can "update" it if you get a more recent version of Python.

What you are [trying to download](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/os) seems to be a dummy `os` module that contains a single line in its `setupy.py` that states:

```
raise RuntimeError("Package 'os' must not be downloaded from pypi")
```

and that's because *you don't download it* nor do you update it; it's already available in Python by default.